# Very simple : textarea with min height-rows and 100% height?

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing a `textarea` element.
And I need to give it the right vertical size.

The container Div have right size. (100%)
I want to give a min-height or min rows, to provide a scroll if necessary, and a height of 100% (the 100 % of div).
I can't. I don't know how to do this. I need an example.

Comment: By default `textarea` gives you `scroll`.  Can you be specific?

Answer (score 9):

The very basic example is

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="height:100%;border:1px solid green;">
    <textarea style="min-height:100px;height:100%;width:100%;border:1px solid red;"></textarea>
</div>

</body>
```

Borders are only to show dimensions. But in your case it might be more complicated. Please look at the definition of a [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) and [height calculation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property).